# Only run the function that is connected to the button that the user last clicked

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have 3 buttons in my application to make the user be able to add different icons to a map depending on which button the user clicks. The problem I had was that if the user would first click button1 and then button2, both functions would execute when the user clicked on the map. I only want the function to be executed that is connected to the button that the user clicked the last time. That is why I have written the following code. I wonder why this code doesn't work and what would be the smartest way to handle this problem.

```
     var latestClick; //The variable to check which button the user clicked the last time

    On(button1, "click", function(evt){
        latestClick = "button1";
    });

    On(button2, "click", function(evt) {
        latestClick = "button2";
    });

    On(button3, "click", function(evt) {
        latestClick = "button3";
    });

        if(latestClick == "button1") {
            On(map, "click", function(evt){ 
                PictureMarkerSymbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol("images/info/info.png", 20, 20);
                mapPoint = esri.geometry.webMercatorToGeographic(evt.mapPoint); 
                pointClick = new Graphic(new Point (evt.mapPoint), PictureMarkerSymbol);
                graphics.add(pointClick);
                name = prompt("Vad vill du ange för namn för denna punkt");
                info = prompt("Vänligen mata in information till punkten");
                url = prompt("Bifoga gärna en bild på informationspunkten");
                pointClick = pointClick.setInfoTemplate(new InfoTemp(name, info + "<br>" +  "<img src = " + url + ">"));
            });
        }

        else if(latestClick == "button2") {
            On(map, "click", function(evt){ 
                PictureMarkerSymbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol("images/rastplats/rastplats.png", 20, 20);
                mapPoint = esri.geometry.webMercatorToGeographic(evt.mapPoint); 
                pointClick = new Graphic(new Point (evt.mapPoint), PictureMarkerSymbol);
                graphics.add(pointClick);
                name = prompt("Ange namn på rastplatsen");
                info = prompt("Ange information för rastplatsen");
                url = prompt("Bifoga en bild på rastplatsen");
                pointClick = pointClick.setInfoTemplate(new InfoTemp(name, info + "<br>" +  "<img src = " + url + ">"));
            });
        }

        else if(latestClick == "button3") {
            On(map, "click", function(evt){ 
                PictureMarkerSymbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol("images/matplats/matplats.png", 20, 20);
                mapPoint = esri.geometry.webMercatorToGeographic(evt.mapPoint); 
                pointClick = new Graphic(new Point (evt.mapPoint), PictureMarkerSymbol);
                graphics.add(pointClick);
                name = prompt("Skriv namn på matplatsen");
                info = prompt("Ange information för matplatsen");
                url = prompt("Länka en bild på matplatsen");
                pointClick = pointClick.setInfoTemplate(new InfoTemp(name, info + "<br>" +  "<img src = " + url + ">"));
            });
        }
```

Comment: Christian, the code seems to be incomplete.  According to the above code, the map click events should never have been fired.  We need to see more to debug.

Comment: I think you should change the order of checking the vale of `latestClick` and the `onclick` handler of the `map`. The value of `latestClick` should be checked in the `onclick` handler and there needs to be only one `onclick` handler for an element.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Will. The code shared does not show full flow. It looks like none of the map event is initialize as latestClick would be undefined till one of the button is clicked.

Assuming, you have some logic to call the map event initialization after the buttons are clicked. It looks like you are not calling it once, so multiple map click Handles will be created. you need to destory the previously set handle before setting up the map click event again. like below.

```
    var mapClickHandle;
    if(latestClick == "button1") {
        mapClickHandle && mapClickHandle.remove();
        mapClickHandle = On(map, "click", function(evt){ 
            PictureMarkerSymbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol("images/info/info.png", 20, 20);
            mapPoint = esri.geometry.webMercatorToGeographic(evt.mapPoint); 
            pointClick = new Graphic(new Point (evt.mapPoint), PictureMarkerSymbol);
            graphics.add(pointClick);
            name = prompt("Vad vill du ange för namn för denna punkt");
            info = prompt("Vänligen mata in information till punkten");
            url = prompt("Bifoga gärna en bild på informationspunkten");
            pointClick = pointClick.setInfoTemplate(new InfoTemp(name, info + "<br>" +  "<img src = " + url + ">"));
        });
    }
    else if(latestClick == "button2") {
        mapClickHandle && mapClickHandle.remove();
        mapClickHandle = On(map, "click", function(evt){ 
            PictureMarkerSymbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol("images/rastplats/rastplats.png", 20, 20);
            mapPoint = esri.geometry.webMercatorToGeographic(evt.mapPoint); 
            pointClick = new Graphic(new Point (evt.mapPoint), PictureMarkerSymbol);
            graphics.add(pointClick);
            name = prompt("Ange namn på rastplatsen");
            info = prompt("Ange information för rastplatsen");
            url = prompt("Bifoga en bild på rastplatsen");
            pointClick = pointClick.setInfoTemplate(new InfoTemp(name, info + "<br>" +  "<img src = " + url + ">"));
        });
    }
    else if(latestClick == "button3") {
        mapClickHandle && mapClickHandle.remove();
        mapClickHandle = On(map, "click", function(evt){ 
            PictureMarkerSymbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol("images/matplats/matplats.png", 20, 20);
            mapPoint = esri.geometry.webMercatorToGeographic(evt.mapPoint); 
            pointClick = new Graphic(new Point (evt.mapPoint), PictureMarkerSymbol);
            graphics.add(pointClick);
            name = prompt("Skriv namn på matplatsen");
            info = prompt("Ange information för matplatsen");
            url = prompt("Länka en bild på matplatsen");
            pointClick = pointClick.setInfoTemplate(new InfoTemp(name, info + "<br>" +  "<img src = " + url + ">"));
        });
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works. I replaced the if statements with onclick handlers in my application though. Thank you very much. @TKambi

Comment: Glad I could help. Mark the question as answered.